# Unable to cast object of type 'CRUD_XML_MVC.Models.Billing' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 application I am using the below code:

```
   Billing WCFBill = new Billing();
   WCFBill.ID = XRec.ID;
   WCFBill.Customer = XRec.Customer;
   WCFBill.Date = XRec.Date;
   WCFBill.Description = XRec.Description;
   WCFBill.Type = XRec.Type;
   WCFBill.Hours = XRec.Hours;
>  var result = ((IEnumerable<Billing>)WCFBill).Cast<Billing>().ToList();
   List<Billing> WCFBillList = new List<Billing>();
   WCFBillList.AddRange(result);
```

The indicated line above is throwing the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'CRUD_XML_MVC.Models.Billing' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CRUD_XML_MVC.Models.Billing]'

Comment: The more urgently you need help, the less urgently we want to help you. You need to include what you tried, we aren't a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this tells us that `WCFBill` is of type `Billing`

```
Billing WCFBill = new Billing();
```

Then this line (relevant part snipped) says you are trying to cast a `Billing` object to type `IEnumerable<Billing>` which is impossible:

```
(IEnumerable<Billing>)WCFBill
```

Answer (score 1):

`WCFBill` is a single instance of `Billing`, and you're trying to convert it to a collection.

Replace the last 3 lines:

```
var result = ((IEnumerable<Billing>)WCFBill).Cast<Billing>().ToList();
List<Billing> WCFBillList = new List<Billing>();
WCFBillList.AddRange(result);
```

With this:

```
var WCFBillList = new List<Billing> { WCFBill };
```